# How to show http errors on presentation layer on networks http calls

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, error-handling, authorization

I have custom exception class bellow

```
class Failure implements Exception {
  String cause;
  Failure(this.cause);
}
```

and have bellow class to call login request

```
class Http {
  void login(String userName, String password) async {
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };

    var data = {
      'client_id': '..',
      'client_secret': '...',
      'grant_type': 'password',
      'scope': '...',
      'username': userName,
      'password': password,
    };

    var url = Uri.parse('http://x.com/connect/token');
    var res = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: data);
    if (res.statusCode != 200) {
      throw 'http.post error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}';
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is how can I handle errors properly on the presentation layer

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String routeName = '/login';

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController _userName = TextEditingController();

  final TextEditingController _password = TextEditingController();
  late bool _obscurePassword;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _obscurePassword = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 16),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _userName,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: Text('username')),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'not empty';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _password,
                obscureText: _obscurePassword,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.password),
                  label: const Text('password'),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      _obscurePassword
                          ? Icons.visibility
                          : Icons.visibility_off,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _obscurePassword = !_obscurePassword;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'not empty';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  onLoginSubmit(context);
                },
                child: const Text('login'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
//-----> how handle errors and show on UI , I get Error: http.post error: statusCode= 400 on console right now
  void onLoginSubmit(BuildContext context) async {
    Http http = Http();
    // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      //save token
      try {
        http.login(_userName.text, _password.text);
      } catch (e, s) {
        print(s);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get `Error: http.post error: statusCode= 400` in console right now, whats the problem?
and If there is a brief article to handle HTTP request secure and properly please provide it in the comments or answer bellow

Comment: instead of print, you can use [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast)

Comment: @JahidulIslam He is probably using print for debugging purposes...

Answer (score 0):

Use Snackbar if you have scaffold

```
try {
     http.login(_userName.text, _password.text);
} catch (e, s) {
     const snackBar = SnackBar(
         content: Text('Error!'),
     );

     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

Or any other toast package

Comment: Thank you, It didn't work.I got `Error: http.post error: statusCode= 400` in console

Comment: how to handle an Error on Http class , did I code it right?

Answer (score 0):

Use await keyword to process Future requests such as an HTTP post request
First change `void login(...)` in your HTTP class to `Future<void> login(...)`
Then use await keyword when you want to call this method for example in your UI

```
void onLoginSubmit(BuildContext context) async {
    Http http = Http();
    // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      //save token
      try {
        await http.login(_userName.text, _password.text);
      } catch (e, s) {
        debugPrint(s);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use `debugPrint` from `dart:foundation` library instead of `print`